# knex increment upsert - increment if record creation fails

Tags: sql, upsert, knex.js

I want to try and create a new record, but if that fails, simply update (increment) a value in that record

```
  await databaseService.knex('myTable')
  .insert({
    id: id1,
    value: 0
  })
  .onConflict(['id1'])
  .increment({
    value: 1
  });
```

Unfortunately it seems you cannot chain .increment after onConflict. I am wondering if there is a way I can do this with knex or do I need to drop into raw SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With on conflict for update part `merge` should be used https://knexjs.org/#Builder-merge

something like this might work:

```
  await databaseService.knex('myTable')
  .insert({
    id: id1,
    value: 0
  })
  .onConflict(['id'])
  .merge({
    value: knex.raw("?? + ?", ["value", 1])
  });
```

https://runkit.com/embed/krdgetjij9xh

Comment: what if it's a bulk insert ?